# How to stop onClick function midway?

Tags: reactjs

I scribbled this example to ask for solution. I give two functions to the link button. The first one is a conditional. If the condition is false, then everything's good and the second function can do its thing. But if the condition is met, then I want to stop the first and the second functions from happening. I am looking for a code that would stop the function from performing, event.StopPropagation did not work, are there other solutions?

```
function1 (e) {
        const dancers = this.state.dancers;
        if (array.length < 16) {
            alert("Error"),
            e.StopPropagation?
        }
    }

function2() {
return function 
}

<Link to={{ pathname: "/example" }} ><button className="create-button" onClick={(e) => { this.function1(e); this.function2();}}>Go to example</button></Link>
```

Comment: Why not just put that logic in one function handler and only call `function2` when the condition is false? Seems unnecessarily convoluted.

Comment: That is true. Seems I've spent too much time overthinking this and missing the simple solution. Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`stopPropagation` prevents further event handlers from being triggered.

You don't have further event handlers, you only have **one**. It just calls two functions in sequence.

The first function needs to return a value indicating if the second function should run or not. Then you can use an `if`.

```
onClick={(e) => { 
    const continue = this.function1(e); 
    if (continue) this.function2();
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

if function2 is  dependent on function 1 then you should execute it inside function one

```
function1 (e) {
        const dancers = this.state.dancers;
        if (array.length < 16) {
            alert("Error"),

        } else{
  function2();
}
    }

function2() {
return function 
}

<Link to={{ pathname: "/example" }} ><button className="create-button" onClick={(e) => { this.function1(e); }}>Go to example</button></Link>
```

Other way is you can return boolean value from function1 and execute function 2 based on that

```
function1 (e) {
        const dancers = this.state.dancers;
        return array.length < 16
    }

function2() {
return function 
}

<Link to={{ pathname: "/example" }} ><button className="create-button" onClick={(e) => { if(this.function1(e)){ this.function2();}}}>Go to example</button></Link>
```